# How can integration of $\int_{0}^{\epsilon} p(R) dR$ where p(R) is given by $\frac{2^R-1}{a}$ equates approximately to $\epsilon$?

Tags: integration

I have an integral problem p(R) is given as $\frac{2^R-1}{a}$ and the question is saying that integrating it from 0 to $\epsilon$ leads to $\epsilon$ itself, I am getting:
$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\frac {2^R-1}{a} dR = 
\frac{2^{\epsilon}log_2e}{a}-\frac{log_2e}{a}-\frac{\epsilon}{a}$ but I am not able to get $\epsilon$. How should I proceed? 
Further it is given that for limit changed to $K\epsilon$ the same integral will give $\epsilon/K$.

Comment: That seems to be wrong: you won't get $\;\epsilon\;$, though there are some mistakes with the integration. Besides other things, the factor $\;\frac1a\;$ won't allow that. Are you sure of what you're asking? The last part is also pretty unclear: for quantity $\;K\epsilon\;$ the same... **what** ? will give...??

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed correctly:

$$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{2^R-1}a=\frac1a\left(\frac{2^R}{\log 2}-R\right)_0^\epsilon=\frac1a\left(\frac{2^\epsilon}{\log 2}-\epsilon-\frac1{\log2}\right)$$

and you can't get $\;\epsilon\;$ at all> even that $\;\frac1a\;$ factor there spoils it all.

Comment: Actually I am trying to solve an integral in which $p(R)=1-e^{\frac{-(2^R-1)}{a}}$ for very large value of a $p(R)=\frac{2^R-1}{a}$ not sure of which equation to solve I have tried the second one. May be should have tried the second one.

Comment: @Ankit I don't understand: integrating a function $\;f\;$ and integrating $\;e^f\;$ are very, very different things in general. Is this integral perhaps for some kind of differential equation?

Comment: as 'a' is very large so expanding exponential function will lead to $1-\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ ignoring $x^2 $ and terms here after we will get the same .

Comment: @Ankit Ok, so that was an approximation...but as you can see, we *still* don't get $\;\epsilon\;$ with your proposed integral

Comment: true, actually this problem is a part of large problem of my wireless course, may be I am losing somewhere track in between. Anyways Thanks!!!

Comment: Just one question which is related to my problem but not this question I will be grateful if you can answer that, if Inverse distribution function for $\epsilon$ is given by $F^-1(\epsilon)$ then for $K\epsilon$ will it be given by $F^-1(\epsilon/K)$

Comment: @Ankit I'm not sure, and it may depend on what $\;K\;$ is. If it is a constant then I think the answer may be *yes* .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46462/discussion-between-ankit-and-donantonio).

Comment: Thanks you solved my issue, is there any book which can give me more details about this inverse distribution function, any book about probability

Comment: There are several books, some of them very good: Ross "Introd. to Probability" , Miller & Freund "Prob. and Statistics for engineers",  Feller "An Introd. to Probability Theory", Loeve "Probability Theory I, II" , Bertsekas & Tsitsiklis "Introd. to Probability", etc.